# Generating a single dict using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using Python to construct a Markov chain generator. The chain model is constructed from the training data, and offers the ability to look up a sequence of words to find out what the next word is most likely to be.

The chain model is a dictionary, with tuple keys ("states", which represent a sequence of words), and dict values (which represent the choice of words that can come after that sequence). The choice dicts have string keys (which represent each word) and int values (which represent the frequency of that word). For example:

```py
>>> make_model("I went to the shop then I went home then I went to bed")
{ (BEGIN, BEGIN): {"I", 1},
  (BEGIN, "I"): {"went", 1},
  ("I", "went"): {"to": 2, "home": 1},
  ("went", "to"): {"the": 1, "bed": 1},
  ("to", "the"): {"shop": 1},
  ... }
```

However, I'm trying to make model generation as fast as possible. In order to do this I'm trying to use the `multiprocessing` package. My attempt can be boiled down into 3 steps:

1. Split the corpus of sentences up into  `n` segments, where `n` is the number of available processors.
2. Create a partial model per processor using `multiprocessing.Pool().map`.
3. Combine the models back into a single model.

1 and 2 are very fast. However, I'm struggling with the 3rd step. The only way I can think of to do this means using 3 nested `for` loops (partial models -> states -> choices) to make a single dict with states from all partial models and all word choice frequencies correctly summed -- on a single processor. But this approach, overall, is slower than doing the *whole thing* on a single processor (and then not needing step 3 at all).

I've tried to make the final model dict a `multiprocessing.Manager().dict()`, but that's *far* slower (I suspect because it's being passed around and locked/unlocked so much). I've tried to make the internal dicts instances of `multiprocessing.Manager().dict()` or `multiprocessing.Value()`, but `multiprocessing` does not allow me to create these object while programme flow is divided between multiple processors - I'd have to create them beforehand.

How can I implement multiprocessing in the formation of a single dict?

Comment: You have a couple of typos in your model example: `(BEGIN, "I"): ("went", 1},` should be `(BEGIN, "I"): {"went", 1},` . And `("I", "went"): {"to": 2, "home", 1},` should be `("I", "went"): {"to": 2, "home": 1},` if I am not mistaken. But I get your point.

Comment: @Perplexabot Quite right, thank you for the fixes!

Comment: How big are these models? Merging them might be slow because they just contain a lot of data, in which case you can't really win with `multiprocessing`.

Comment: @nneonneo They are several thousand sentences long - I don't think I can win with either multiprocessing or regularprocessing

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe make it *slightly* faster by using `collections.Counter`s as your keys:

```
from collections import Counter
d1 = {("a", "b"): Counter({"c": 3, "d": 4})}
d2 = {("a", "b"): Counter({"c": 5, "e": 6})}
d1['a','b'] += d2['a','b']
# d1 is now {('a', 'b'): Counter({'c': 8, 'e': 6, 'd': 4})}
```

`Counter`s merge naturally so they might be a little faster. In terms of code length, this is definitely a lot nicer:

```
final = collections.defaultdict(Counter)
for d in results:
    for key in d:
        final[key] += d[key]
```

but it might not actually be substantially faster if there's a lot of data to merge.

Comment: In my experience I've found `Counter` to actually be pretty slow, though that might not be a fair comparison as I was using Cython at the time. I'll test this and report back.

Comment: It works! But it takes about double the time that *not* using defaultdict and Counter takes.

Comment: Hmm, too bad. But like I said - the models themselves are probably too big to be merged easily, so there’s no win to be had by multiprocessing. Heck, for a given corpus I would expect that the number of word pairs would be roughly proportional to the total length - so the merge operation is going to do about as much work as scanning the whole corpus.

Comment: One way to maybe make this more efficient would be to simply store the dicts retrieved from the threads then do some kind of cascaded or multi lookup at generation time. It slows generation down by the number of threads you used, but that cost might be much smaller overall.

Comment: Oooohhhhhh... I don't much like that, but thinking about it, that is probably the way to go here. At least I'll be able to have one processor look at each list during the lookup.